# Converting a heap to a BST in O(n) time?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o, binary-search-tree, binary-heap

I think that I know the answer and the minimum complexity is **O(nlogn)**.

But is there any way that I can make an binary search tree from a heap in **O(n)** complexity?

Comment: make BST from Heap in O(n) is MORE efficient then O(nlogn).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no algorithm for building a BST from a heap in O(n) time.  The reason for this is that given n elements, you can build a heap from them in O(n) time.  If you have a BST for a set of values, you can sort them in O(n) time by doing an inorder traversal.  If you could build a BST from a heap in O(n) time, you could then have an O(n) sorting algorithm by

1. Building the heap in O(n) time,
2. Converting the heap to a BST in O(n) time, and
3. Walking the BST in O(n) time to get a sorted sequence.

Therefore, it is not possible to convert a heap to a BST in O(n) time (or in o(n log n) time, where o is **[little-o notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation)**).

However, it is possible to build a BST from a heap in O(n log n) time by repeatedly dequeueing the maximum value from the BST and inserting it as the rightmost node in the tree.  (You'd need to store a pointer there for fast access; just inserting at the root repeatly would take O(n<sup>2</sup>) time.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you!
it helped me very much!

Comment: Thanks! Helped me too :)